# Error during SonarScanner execution after executing SonarScanner end command

Tags: sonarqube, sonarscanner

I am getting error during SonarScanner execution, while executing the third command:

1. dotnet  begin /k:"project-key"
2. dotnet build
3. dotnet  end

Below is the screen shot of the exception:

ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.sonar.sslr.api.typed.ActionParser.(ActionParser.java:59)
at org.sonar.javascript.parser.JavaScriptParser.(JavaScriptParser.java:33)`enter code here`
at org.sonar.javascript.parser.JavaScriptParserBuilder.createParser(JavaScriptParserBuilder.java:31)
at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptSensor.(JavaScriptSensor.java:136)
at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptSensor.(JavaScriptSensor.java:100)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:606)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponents(DefaultPicoContainer.java:587)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentsByType(ComponentContainer.java:290)
at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.AbstractExtensionDictionnary.completeScannerExtensions(AbstractExtensionDictionnary.java:82)
at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.AbstractExtensionDictionnary.getExtensions(AbstractExtensionDictionnary.java:77)
at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.AbstractExtensionDictionnary.getFilteredExtensions(AbstractExtensionDictionnary.java:67)
at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorExtensionDictionnary.selectSensors(ModuleSensorExtensionDictionnary.java:40)
at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:52)
at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)
at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:52)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:82)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:400)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:395)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:392)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:358)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:141)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:73)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @1bf39d06
at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464)
at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336)
at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.(Enhancer.java:73)
... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @1bf39d06
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:61)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.(ReflectUtils.java:52)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:243)
at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329)
... 65 more
ERROR:
The SonarScanner did not complete successfully
18:19:06.186  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1

[SonarScanner exception screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEXxt.png)

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem and solved it by reverting to openjdk 15.0.2 (16.0 is latest as of today and seems to create this issue, I install using https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/openjdk#versionhistory)